# Какие есть средства графического анализа кода на PHP?

Tags: php

Знаю, что есть такая тема как профилирование и графические утилиты, выводящие инфу в приятном для глаз виде. Что-то наподобие этого

[image]
([ссылка на изображение](http://www.instanceof.ru/scr/03.12.2009-03.09.02.png))

Отсюда вопрос: существуют ли утилиты, которые могут отобразить архитектуру проекта каким-нибудь более лучшим способом, чем просто текст? Интересует php и среда linux, но если есть для винды, тоже сгодится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне нравится [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html)

Comment: Спасибо! Буду ковырять))

Answer (score 1):

Использую xhprof, не знаю лучший ли он в мире, но попробовал разобрался и просто лень еще что-то попробовать другого.